# How to get element text to WCHAR* in pugixml

Tags: c++, xml, pugixml

I'm using pugixml library to parse xml files.

How can I get the node text to WCHAR* in pugixml ?

Answer (score 0):

You have two basic options:

1. Compile pugixml with `PUGIXML_WCHAR_MODE` define set in `pugiconfig.hpp` or in compile options, then use the usual methods to get node text (i.e. `node.text().get()` or `node.child_value()`).
2. Use pugi::as_wide function, i.e. `pugi::as_wide(node.child_value())`.

See http://pugixml.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/docs/manual/dom.html#manual.dom.unicode for details.