# Use std::wstring with plugixml

Tags: c++, xml, visual-c++-2022

I would like to read an XML file into my application. PLUGIXML is used to parse the XML file.  PUGIXML_WCHAR_MODE has been deactivated in the config file. My data structure in the corresponding class looks like this:

```
class Country {
public:
    int ID;
    std::wstring Name;
};
```

My algorithm for reading the file is this

```
std::vector<Country> readCountriesFromXML(const std::string& filename) {
    
    xml_document doc;
    
    doc.load_file(filename.c_str());
    for (xml_node countryNode : doc.child("Daten").children("Country")) {
        Country country;
        country.ID = countryNode.child("ID").text().as_int();
        country.Name = countryNode.child("Name").text().as_string();
        std::wstring wName(country.Name.begin(), country.Name.end());
        country.Name = wName;
        countries.push_back(country);
    }
    
    return countries;
}
```

I can't fill the name of the country that was created as wstring and I don't know how to get the conversion from string to wstring when I try to use wstring it doesn't work.

I had tried to convert the string by setting wString without success. I have also replaced as_string with get with the same result

Comment: Can you clarify what "PUGIXML_WCHAR_MODE has been deactivated" means? Normally you'd want that set to use wide strings. [How to get element text to WCHAR* in pugixml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22356502/how-to-get-element-text-to-wchar-in-pugixml) offers that advice and another alternative.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/8Y99zKT4b

Comment: Offtopic: mixing English and other language in xml format (`Daten`) is a bad thing.